# How to combile query conditions inside bracket in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

In laravel 5, I am using below query builder

```
$user_social = DB::table('users')
        ->where('email','=',$credentials['email'])
        ->where('facebook', '!=', '')
        ->orWhere('google', '!=', '')
        ->get(['facebook','google']);
```

And I am getting this query, generated by query builder

```
"select * from `users` where `email` = ? and `facebook` != ? or `google` != ?"
```

What changes needed to make query like this.

```
"select * from `users` where `email` = ? and (`facebook` != ? or `google` != ?")
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#advanced-wheres):

```
$user_social = DB::table('users')
        ->where('email', '=', $credentials['email'])
        ->orWhere(function($query)
        {
            $query->where('facebook', '!=', '')
                  ->where('google', '!=', '');
        })
        ->get(['facebook','google']);
```

This generates a query like this

```
select * from users where email = 'email' or (facebook != '' and google != '')
```

Comment: Its generating query "select * from `users` where `email` = ? or (`facebook` != ? and `google` != ?)"
But I can now easily change it to "select * from `users` where `email` = ? and (`facebook` != ? or `google` != ?)"

Thanks a lot